# Gothic 2 with mod New Balance july 2023 ver. I am not able to move or open inventory

Tags: mods, gothic-2

I just installed New Balance mod (version july 2023) into my Gothic 2 Golden edition. But I encountered a few problems:

1. I cannot move. I can only move when my weapon is drawn.
2. I cannot open inventory.
3. Some of the textures are not loaded properly. (for example some NPCs have a body missing with only the head being visible)

My NTB specs :

- GPU :Nvidia Geforce 1660Ti
- CPU : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10300H CPU @ 2.50GHz   2.50 GHz
- RAM : 16GB
- OS : WIN 11 64 Bit

How can I fix this problem?

I don't know what may cause this problem. I fixed the previous problem by enabling the variable Windowed mode to 1. The previous problem was I got a black screen if I started a new game or loaded previous saves.

Thank you for your answers and advice.